# How to convert Data to URL()?

Tags: ios, swift, url, data-conversion

I have an image in the form of `Data` obtained from firebase:

```
if let img = selectedPost.media[numberMedia + 1].image {
    let data = (img.pngData() as Data?)!//here
```

I need to convert this value into a URL. How can I do that?

I have tried:

```
let imageUrl = URL(dataRepresentation: data, relativeTo: "https://URL")
```

but get

> Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'URL?'

Comment: You have an image in the form of data? So it’s a byte? I’d have the data in one column and the URL link in another and reference the data from the URL column

Comment: If you already have the image data in memory you just need to write it to disk (documents directory or library) and use that local file URL

Comment: FYI - `let data = (img.pngData() as Data?)!` should just be `if let data = img.pngData() { // do something }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't create a URL from data , only if this url is pointing to a local storage such as file url in documents / library , So you have

- Remote url - > read data from it
- local data  -> write to local url
- local data -> upload to server and get a remote url referring to it
- **X** local data -> get remote url locally without uploading **X** > can't be

Also use

```
guard let data = img.pngData() else { return }
```

instead of the un safe `!`

Comment: if you have the url in Firebase , you can only pull the data from it , and save it locally in documents as said to get a local url , to upload to firebase storage you need data and call the method `.putData` that points to the correct child may be same child that you read from to overwrite the new data